# Wordpress Update Role using API Cross site

Tags: rest-api

I want to get user by email address. Getting issue with custom api endpoint route.

```
function getUserByEmail( $data ) {

        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $data['email'] );

        if ( empty( $user ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        return $user;
    }


    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/updateRole/(?P<email>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'getUserByEmail',
        ) );
    } );
```

> Error :  {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found
>   matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}

Comment: Can you please add some more information? "Getting issue" is a little vague.
Think of:
- Steps to Reproduce
- Actual Results
- Expected Results <-- I guess this is the User object?

Comment: Sure, Actually I have 3 website. example1.com example2.com and example3.com

Comment: manage role from example1.com if user update role in example1.com then it should be update in example2.com and example3.com

Comment: What is the error or output you're getting now? (= actual result)

Comment: Route not found

Comment: {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}